# reproduce/break rows based on field value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have my `dataframe` as:

```
id        date     value
1         2016     3
2         2016     1
1         2018     1
1         2016     1.1
```

Now I want to reproduce rows for some weird reason with logic as:

```
if value > 1
    reproduce row value times - 1
    with value = 1
    or fraction left for last unit
```

for better understanding consider only 1st row of `dataframe` i.e. :

```
id        date     value
1         2016     3
```

which I have broken down into 3 rows as:

```
id        date     value
1         2016     1
1         2016     1
1         2016     1
```

**but consider last row i.e.:**

```
id        date     value
1         2016     1.1
```

**Which is broken as:**

```
id        date     value
1         2016     1
1         2016     0.1
```

i.e. if any fraction is there, this is broken separately, else in one unit

and then group by id and sort by date is obviously easy.

i.e. new `dataframe` will look like:

```
id        date     value
1         2016     1
1         2016     1
1         2016     1
1         2016     1
1         2016     0.1
1         2018     1
2         2016     1
```

The main problem is reproducing rows.

## UPDATED

A sample `dataframe` code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2018,5.1],[2,2018,2],[1,2016,1]], columns=["id", "date", "value"])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### generator

```
def f(df):
  for i, *t, v in df.itertuples():
    while v > 0:
      yield t + [min(v, 1)]
      v -= 1

pd.DataFrame([*f(df)], columns=df.columns)

   id  date  value
0   1  2018    1.0
1   1  2018    1.0
2   1  2018    1.0
3   1  2018    1.0
4   1  2018    1.0
5   1  2018    0.1
6   2  2018    1.0
7   2  2018    1.0
8   1  2016    1.0
```

Comment: Thankyou @piRSquared sir for answering this works as expected !

Answer (score 4):

Using // and % with `pandas` `repeat`

```
s1=df.value//1
s2=df.value%1
s=pd.concat([s1.loc[s1.index.repeat(s1.astype(int))],s2[s2!=0]]).sort_index()
s.loc[s>=1]=1
newdf=df.reindex(df.index.repeat((s1+(s2).ne(0)).astype(int)))  
newdf['value']=s.values
newdf
Out[236]:
   id  date  value
0   1  2016    1.0
0   1  2016    1.0
0   1  2016    1.0
1   2  2016    1.0
2   1  2018    1.0
3   1  2016    1.0
3   1  2016    0.1
```

Comment: @AashishGahlawat yw :-)